# What is the proper way to get Three.js used within Webpack so I can use OrbitControls?

Tags: three.js, webpack

In my webpack config:

```
resolve: {
      alias: {
        'three': path.resolve('node_modules', 'three/build/three.js'),
        'OrbitControls': path.resolve('node_modules', 'three/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js'),
        'OBJLoader': path.resolve('node_modules', 'three/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader.js')
      }
```

In my module:

```
import * as THREE from 'three' // if I do import THREE from 'three' it fails with three being undefined
import OrbitControls from 'OrbitControls'
import OBJLoader from 'OBJLoader'
```

If I use `import * THREE from 'three'` all is well and I can get THREE to be defined and complete the cube tutorial without hassle. If I change to `import * as THREE from 'three'` three.js is loaded - so that's not the problem?

How do I get the `OrbitControls` and the `OBJLoader` to load? When I try to get them to load, I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: THREE is not defined(…)` within `OrbitControls.js`: `THREE.OrbitControls = function ( object, domElement ) {` THREE is undefined.

So there's a problem with the packaging of the modules? I installed this from https://www.npmjs.com/package/three

So what gives? Is it a problem how Three.js is packaged on npm or is it a misconfiguration in my webpack.config? Is there a way to tell webpack "let's package the root three.js file, and then package the OrbitControls.js file"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to install the `three-orbit-controls` and the `three-obj-loader` via npm.

Then in my module, it was simply requiring them:

```
var OBJLoader = require('three-obj-loader')(THREE)
var OrbitControls = require('three-orbit-controls')(THREE)
```

All set!